# Regex to find space, square bracket, any number, closing square bracket and comma e.g., ( [number],)

Tags: regex

I am new to Regex and I need help in creating a Regex that is able to find space, open square brackets, any number, close square brackets and commas in a text. For example:

Text File:

```
{
"text": [
      {
        "text": "textg [65]",
        "text": "text text text [65], text [65], text [65], text [65]"
      },
      {
        "text": "text text [77]",
        "text": "textpoint text [77], textgrade [77], text [77], text [77]"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want only ***(space)[65],*** and ***(space)[77],*** as output.

Comment: Hi @Coder, add an answer below and verify it on regex101 website, Please have a try.  In short, you need to escape the special chars in the regex expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\s\[\d+\],
```

in total 6 matches are found from the example you provided:

```
 [65],
 [65],
 [65],
 [77],
 [77],
 [77],
```

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/ndGlzr/1)

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem. It is not working in my real dataset. For example: text text [65]"    "text": "text text [65], text text [10], text text [22], text text text text(s) [11], text text text [22], text text [31], text text text [12]

Comment: Here it only finds the first one and not the rest.

Comment: HI @Coder, I tried it in regex101, for your new example, it found all of them. "text text [65], text text [65], text text [65], text text text text(s) [65], text text text [65], text text [65], text text text [65] ", https://regex101.com/r/wwqTtM/1  if you only find the first one in your real one,  I suspect what you encouter is  you are using find_first instead of find_all function.  what is the program languag and function you use for the regex extraction here?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the dataset in the question after adding ' "text": [ ' now it is only working for the first one. Can you please try it with the above-updated dataset.

Comment: for "text text [65]" "text": "text text [65], text text [10], text text [22], text text text text(s) [11], text text text [22], text text [31], text text text [12]", checking in regex101, it also found all 6 matches. https://regex101.com/r/Y6jULR/1    [65],
 [10],
 [22],
 [11],
 [22],
 [31],

Comment: I get it now. Thanks. It was the issue with setting Regex options as you mentioned before :) after setting it multiLine and globe it worked

Comment: Great to glad that it works for you now.